# GEE Map.addLayer opacity depends on value

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, transparency-opacity

I can draw some red points using the addLayer function:

```
var first = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(-70.48, 43.3631))
                .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
                .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
                .first();

var samples = first.sample({
  numPixels: 10,
  geometries: true,

});


Map.addLayer(samples, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 2000,  color: 'red'}, 'samples');
```

But now I want to draw the points whose opacity depends on one of the band value, for example, B2 band. The bigger the value, the more opaque. Could you tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ee.FeatureCollection.style()` and specify the `styleProperty` to get different styling for different features.

```
var first = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(-70.48, 43.3631))
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
  .first()

var samples = first
  .sample({
    numPixels: 10,
    geometries: true,
  })
  .map(function(feature) {
    var min = 0
    var max = 300
    var opacity = toHex(min, max, feature.getNumber('B2'))
    var fillColor = ee.String('#ff0000').cat(opacity)
    return feature
      .set('style', {
        fillColor: fillColor
      })
  })

var styled = samples.style({
  pointSize: 4,
  width: 0,
  styleProperty: 'style'
})

Map.addLayer(styled, null, 'samples')
Map.centerObject(samples)


function toHex(min, max, value) {
  return ee.Number(value)
    .unitScale(min, max)
    .multiply(255)
    .round()
    .clamp(0, 255)
    .format('%x')
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/04e0749fd40f8b91825c8b80c4c32490